# does kubuntu have a /home/ubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, home-directory

Does kubuntu have a /home/ubuntu directory or a /home/kubuntu directory?

if it has a /home/kubuntu directory, is it possible to rename this to /home/ubuntu without negative side effects?

Sort of an odd question but hopefully someone can fulfill my request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really strange question...

Kubuntu does NOT have such directory unless your **username** is "ubuntu" (or "kubuntu")!

Comment: In a Live-CD or Live-USB system the default username is "ubuntu".